# Concat param with attribute already set

Tags: xslt

### Is it possible in XSLT 1.0 to output a value based on another value "previously output" in the actual xslt document ?

I can't seem to find the right way to say this. Hopefully the example should be easy to understand.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:param name="ServerUrl" select="'http://www.myserver.com/'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <img src="images/image1.jpg">
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($ServerUrl,**Value of current @src**)" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like the following output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.myserver.com/images/image1.jpg"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know this might seem wrong at first but the intent is to keep the XSLT as close as possible as the original HTML to ease further modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet uses the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function with an empty path, which loads the XSLT as an XML document, and then XPath to the `img/@src` attribute value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="ServerUrl" select="'http://www.myserver.com/'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <img src="images/image1.jpg">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ServerUrl, document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@match='/']/html/body/img/@src)" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second `@src` attribute definition will "win" and be generated in the output.

[7.1.3 Creating Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)

> Adding an attribute to an element replaces any existing attribute of
>   that element with the same expanded-name.

Although, I would not recommend this approach. It is confusing to read/understand and not a standard practice.

Comment: Brilliant! Here comes the "one more question" that might complicate things. How do I get the XPath /html/body/img/@src to match the currently processed img/@src?  Preferably using something dynamic like position() or number() (not the ID).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the result of an XPath epression within an attribute for a literal result element.

In XSLT, the 'Attribute Value Template' (AVT) is used for this. To use an AVT you should surround the XPath expression with opening and closing curly braces. AVTs can be combined with literal text in the same attribute, saving the need to use a concat expression.

So, for your example you can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform>
  <xsl:param name="ServerUrl" select="'http://www.myserver.com/'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <img src="{$ServerUrl}images/image1.jpg"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but my intent is not to only replace the variable using AVTs. Mads Hansen's answer seems to provide what I want.